# Read and parse line in C/C++; put tokens in an array or vector or similar structure

Tags: c++, c, parsing, inputstream

I have to submit code to one of the problems in ACM IPC and, as you may know, the time counts a lot. So, I have to read efficiently an input like this:
 The first line will contain the sequence of integer values associated and the second line will contain the sequence of integer values associated with another sequence.
E.g.:

```
3 2 1 4 5 7 6    
3 1 2 5 6 7 4   
7 8 11 3 5 16 12 18   
8 3 11 7 16 18 12 5   
255  
255
```

I have to put the 1st line in an array and the second in another and pass both in a function.

How do I read and put these in C/C++? I was thinking in a C way, but my approach would have 2 while's... 
I have preference reading with scanf, but the parsing can be done as you want.

Please , help this newb!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the lines using [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Then use a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to parse each line. As this is for a competition, you won't be wanting actual code.

Comment: It is not for competition, it's for training. We only submit the code in a platform that the university developped, but the problems are from ACM IPC or similar. So, any code would be very helpfull. Thanks, anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector< int > ints_t;

void dump_ints( const ints_t& input )
{
    std::copy(
        input.begin(),
        input.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator< int >( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void foo( const ints_t& first, const ints_t& second )
{
    dump_ints( first );
    dump_ints( second );
}

bool parse_line( std::istream& is, ints_t* output )
{
    std::string line;
    if ( std::getline( is, line ) )
    {
        std::istringstream raw_ints( line );
        std::copy(
            std::istream_iterator< int >( raw_ints ),
            std::istream_iterator< int >(),
            std::back_inserter( *output ) );
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool parse( std::istream& is, ints_t* first, ints_t* second )
{
    const bool result = parse_line( is, first ) && parse_line( is, second );
    return result;
}

void run( std::istream& is )
{
    while ( is )
    {
        ints_t first;
        ints_t second;
        if ( parse( is, &first, &second ) )
        {
            foo( first, second );
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //if you want to read input from file use ifstream and comment istringstream 
//    std::ifstream is( "put_here_a_path_to_input_file" );
    std::istringstream is( 
        "3 2 1 4 5 7 6\n"
        "3 1 2 5 6 7 4\n"
        "7 8 11 3 5 16 12 18\n"
        "8 3 11 7 16 18 12 5\n"
        "255\n"
        "255\n" 
        );
    run( is );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use strtok() and strdup().

See [example of using strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) and [strdup()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html). strtok() would then be used to extract the individual tokens - strdup() to allocate space an copy them.

Comment: Yes, but remember that `strtok()` is the worst-designed function in the C library, so you might want to look for a safer function that does something similar.  `strdup()` is not in the C90 standard (I don't have the C99), but it's easy to write.

Comment: @David:I'd agree that `strtok` has a poor interface, but are you honestly claiming that it's worse than `gets`? I think that claim would require considerable justification.

Comment: @Jerry:  `strtok()` has hidden internal state, which I believe is more important than the interface, and which I believe makes it the worst-designed function.  `gets()` is a contender, though.

Comment: @David:IMO, `gets` is clearly worse -- there's **no** safe way to use `gets`. While `strtok` can be clumsy, it's still possible to use it safely under some circumstances. Quite a few functions have hidden internal state (e.g., `rand()`, many of the time functions).